# Simple form bootstrap design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

How do i make simple form to use [image]

my current simple mobile form looks like this

```
<%= f.input :c_regular, :label => "Regular"%>
 <%= f.input :c_medium, :label => "Medium"%>
 <%= f.input :c_premium, :label => "Premium"%>
 <%= f.input :c_diesel, :label => "Diesel"%>
 <%= f.input :c_delivery, :label => "Delivery Charges"%>
```

I want the form to have a $ infront like it has @ in the image above.

thanks in advance.\

[image]

```
<div class="row">
        <%= simple_form_for @contact, url: supplier_contacts_path do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :first_name, label: "First Name" %>
        <%= f.input :last_name, label: "Last Name"%>
        <%= f.input :business_name, label: "Business Name" %>
        <%= f.input :phone_number, label: "Phone Number" %>
        <%= f.input :cell_number, label: "Mobile Number" %>
        <%= f.input :carrier, :label => "Mobile Carrier", :collection => mobile_carrier, :selected => "Tmobile"%>
        <%= f.input :street_address, label: "Street Address" %>
        <%= f.input :apt_suite, label: "Apt/Suite" %>
        <%= f.input :city, label: "City" %>
        <%= f.input :state, :label => "State", :collection => us_states, :selected => "New Jersey"%>
        <%= f.input :zip_code, :label => "Zip Code"%>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <%= f.input :c_regular, :label => "Regular", class:  "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <%= f.input :c_medium, :label => "Medium"%>
        <%= f.input :c_premium, :label => "Premium"%>
        <%= f.input :c_diesel, :label => "Diesel"%>
        <%= f.input :c_delivery, :label => "Delivery Charges"%>
        <%= f.button :submit, "Add Retailer", class: "btn btn-primary block full-width m-b"%>
        <%end%>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you update your code example above with the changes that you did per the 1st response? I'm guessing a nesting error but need to see your code example to give you a fix

Comment: Added it above. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the following if you are using Bootstrap 3 for your `form_for` or `form_tag`:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
 <%= f.input :c_regular, :label => "Regular", class:  "form-control" %>
</div>
```

---

But if you are using `simple_form_for`, then there are [some issues](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/How-to-use-Bootstrap-3-input-group-in-Simple-Form) with some Bootstrap component like `input_group`.

But luckily there are some workarounds also available.

**Step-1:**

Generate your Bootstrap config file for simple_form if you have not done before using the following command-

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

This would create a config file in the following path of your application root -

```
config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb
```

**Step-2:**

Include the following additional wrappers to your `simple_form_bootstrap.rb` file-

```
  config.wrappers :horizontal_input_group, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label, class: 'col-sm-3 control-label'

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-9' do |ba|
      ba.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'input-group col-sm-12' do |append|
        append.use :input, class: 'form-control'
      end
      ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end
```

**Step-3:**
Modify your `simple_form_for` as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@contact, url: supplier_contacts_path, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
   <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :c_regular,wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do %>
     <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <%= f.input_field :c_regular, :label => "Regular",class: "form-control" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Looks weird now lol. I added the screen shot above for the current form.

Comment: @suyesh I have edited my answer for **simple_form_for** . There are still some components of Bootstrap not supported in simple_form_for as it is described here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/How-to-use-Bootstrap-3-input-group-in-Simple-Form